# How does ADF v1 and v2 handle & signs in company names

Tags: azure-data-factory

I´m trying to use the "USE QUERY" alternative when connecting to a `NAV Odata` feed in `ADF v1`.

I have a `serviceurl` which works, then i switch to use query and write the following:

```
Customers?company='My Company Name'.
```

This works just fine, but one of the companies have an `&` sign in their company name, e.g. `"My & Company'`

I can't really figure out how `ADF` handles % signs because %26 doesn't work, but %27 which is an `'` strangely does..

I've tried the following:

```
Customers?company='My%20%26%20Company
```

Any ideas?